# Kdewallet unwittingly meddle with pip

Tags: kde, pip

As I did many times before, I just run the command:

```
pip3 search xlib
```

Then I get this completely useless and unwanted window:

[image: Kdewallet window]

This behavior start perhaps since I installed Kdenlive. BTW, I was just wondering Kdenlive, not the full KDE behaviour.

So, I have two questions :

1. How to just go back to the simple behavior I had with pip3 without getting kdewallet or any other KDE part interfering with pip3?
2. How to disable all other potential KDE interferences in my system?  As I said, I just want Kdenlive wen I explicitly run it, not make KDE manage my system (I use i3 if it is usefull).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem (Arch Linux by the way) and I don't know why it suddenly started happening, but it's suppressed by setting

```
export PYTHON_KEYRING_BACKEND=keyring.backends.null.Keyring
```

in the environment.